What python version does audio dependency not work for kivy?
I'm trying to install kivy libraries to make apps compatible with ios and Android, but I can't do audio dependency during the dependency process. I did pip 2.4 (latest version) and Python used both 3.8 and 3.10, but I still get errors. What should I do? I'm sorry if I'm not good at word selection using a transenter image description herelator.Thank you for your kind response.
I created code to create a virtual environment, but I didn't get the file. Also, I don't really understand the part that I need to create a new one to avoid conflicts... There are a lot of things I don't know about because I'm not good at making code, I'm sorry

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
